# matriz como atributo de una clase ¿como poder acceder a ella desde otra clase? y poder actualizarla

Tags: c++

Nuevamente preguntando acerca del juego de damas chinas en el que estoy trabajando, mi problema es ahora que intento hacer los métodos para realizar el movimiento de la fichas.

En un momento pensé en que movimiento fuera un método de ficha pasando la matriz que esta definida en la clase tablero, pero luego pensé que no tiene sentido que una clase ficha tenga un tablero y pues en tablero no puedo tener un método movimiento, entonces pensé en definir una clase que se llame movimiento, que puede ser abstracta e implementar los métodos en las fichas damas y peones puesto que son diferentes los movimientos.

Ahora la pregunta ¿Cómo le paso la matriz que esta llena con fichas definida en la clase tablero a mi clase movimiento y poder modificarla?.

He intentado pero no he dado con el truco agradezco me puedan dar una idea.
mil gracias saludos.

```
/*
  Archivo de cabecera de la clase Tablero.
*/

#ifndef TABLERO_H
#define TABLERO_H
#include <string>
#include "Ficha.h"
#include "Peon.h"
#include "Casilla.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>
#include"Validacion.h"//se incluye la cabecera de la clase Validacion.

using namespace std;

class Tablero{
    //atributos.
private:
    Ficha***tablero;//triple puntero a Ficha.
    int filas=0,columnas=0,tamanio=0;
    Validacion*valida;//objeto para validar datos.

  //metodos
public:

    Tablero();
    ~Tablero();
    void pedirTamanio();
    int getTamanio();
    void setTamanio(int tam);
    void limpiarMatriz();
    void reservarEspacio();
    void inicializarMatriz();
    void llenarTablero();
    void mostrarTablero();

};
#endif


//archivo Tablero.cpp
//reserva de memoria para la matriz
void Tablero:: reservarEspacio(){
    tablero=new Ficha**[filas];
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        tablero[i]=new Ficha*[columnas];
    }
}
//inicializo la matriz
void Tablero:: inicializarMatriz(){
    limpiarMatriz();
    reservarEspacio();
}

//llenado del tablero
void Tablero:: llenarTablero(){
    inicializarMatriz();

    for(int fil=0;fil<tamanio;fil++){
        for(int col=0;col<tamanio;col++){
            if(fil>=0 && fil<3){
                if(fil %2 !=0){
                    if(col %2 ==0){
                        tablero[fil][col]=new Peon("2");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tablero[fil][col]=new Casilla();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(col %2 ==0){
                        tablero[fil][col]=new Casilla();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tablero[fil][col]=new Peon("2");
                    }
                } 
            }
            else
            {   
                if(fil>=3 && fil<(tamanio-3)){
                    tablero[fil][col]=new Casilla();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(fil>=(tamanio-3) && fil<(tamanio)){
                        if(fil %2 !=0){
                            if(col %2 ==0){
                                tablero[fil][col]=new Peon("1");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                tablero[fil][col]=new Casilla();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(col %2 ==0){
                                tablero[fil][col]=new Casilla();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                tablero[fil][col]=new Peon("1");
                            }
                    } 
                }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}

void Tablero:: mostrarTablero(){
    for(int i=0;i<tamanio;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<tamanio;j++){
            cout<<tablero[i][j]->getColor();
            if(j==tamanio-1){
                cout<<"\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
//que pena olvide subir el código 
//Esta es la matriz y quiero pasarla a otra clase y poder modificarla,espero
```

Comment: Sin ver tu código y como lo has intentado acceder, será difícil ayudarte. ¿ Te has pasado ya por [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Tienes información sobre como funciona el sitio en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Un saludo.

Comment: @Trauma que pena amigo olvide subir el código espero me puedas dar una mano mil gracias.

Comment: El código que has pasado no sirve para nada en cuanto a resolverte la duda. Publica las cabeceras de las clases involucradas, diagramas uml, información que permita hacerse una idea de la relación que hay ahora mismo entre tus clases

Comment: @eferion Que tal la verdad no queria poner tanto codigo,mi duda es en si,

Comment: Peor es poner código que no va a ayudar a resolver tu pregunta, ¿cierto?

Comment: Para acceder al objeto puedes optar por crear una función en `Tablero` que devuelva un puntero o referencia al la matriz... es solo una de las posibilidades y la más simple de implementar, pero eso no implica que te vaya  a servir, "tal cual"

Comment: Hola que pena con todos la verdad soy nuevo por acá y llevo poco programando en c++,subí el archivo.h de Tablero por si sirve de algo quiero es crear una clase movimiento y pesarla mi matriz de fichas quisiera saber la sintaxis correcta ya que falte a la clase de paso por valor , por referencia o puntero mil gracias perdón la molestia

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, cada ficha sí puede saber cómo se mueve, un peon puede conocer sus posibles movimientos y lo mismo para una dama.

Así pues, dada una posición inicial podría devolver, por ejemplo, un array con los posibles movimientos. De la misma manera que cada ficha podría recibir una posición inicial y una final y confirmar si el movimiento es válido o no:

```
class Point
{
public:
  Point(int x, int y)
    : _x{x}, _y{y}
  { }

  public int getX() const
  { return _x; }

  public int getY() const
  { return _x; }

private:
    int _x;
    int _y;
};

class Ficha
{
  virtual std::vector<Point> getMovements(Point currentPosition) const;

  bool isValidMovement(Point currentPosition, Point destination) const
  {
    std::vector<Point> movements = getMovements(currentPosition);

    return std::any_of(std::begin(movements), std::end(movements),
                       [destination](Point const& p){ return destination == p; });
  }
};

class Peon : public Ficha
{
  std::vector<Point> getMovements(Point currentPosition) const override
  {
    std::vector<Point> movements;

    // Rellenar la lista de posibles movimientos del peon

    return movements;
  }
}
```

Si resulta que el tablero puede ser de un tamaño aleatorio entonces las funciones deberán recibir también las dimensiones de dicho tablero.

Este enfoque tiene como principal ventaja que es facil de implementar, mientras que su principal desventaja es que no funciona si una ficha no puede saltar a otra... dado que las diferentes fichas no se conocen entre sí dificilmente podrá tener en cuenta su entorno.

Para tener en cuenta el entorno es necesario tener acceso al tablero de juego... y en este punto coincido contigo, no tiene demasiado sentido que una ficha tenga que conocer el tablero de juego. Sin embargo no tiene por qué ser necesario conocer todo el tablero... bastaría con saber dónde se encuentran las fichas:

```
class Ficha
{
  virtual std::vector<Point> getMovements(Point currentPosition,
                                          std::vector<Point> const& friends,
                                          std::vector<Point> const& enemies)  const;
};

class Peon : public Ficha
{
  std::vector<Point> getMovements(Point currentPosition,
                                  std::vector<Point> const& friends,
                                  std::vector<Point> const& enemies)  const override
  {
    std::vector<Point> movements;

    // Rellenar la lista de posibles movimientos

    return movements;
  }
}
```

Ahora bien, si basamos todo en las posiciones de las fichas vemos que no es tan necesario un array triple (`tablero`) para gestionar el juego. Si cada ficha es capaz de saber dónde se encuentra nos basta con tener un vector de fichas (o dos si nos decantamos por separar las fichas de ambos equipos):

```
class Ficha
{
public:
  Point const& getPosition() const
  { return _position; }

  void moveTo(Point const& newPosition)
  {
    if( isValidMovement(newPosition) )
      _position = newPosition;
  }

private:
  Point _position;
};

class Tablero
{
private:
  std::vector<Ficha> teamA;
  std::vector<Ficha> teamB;
};
```